# getting default values of variables during run time in java

Tags: java, variables, constructor

When i run this program in Eclipse, I get the default values of the variables and not the values which i enter during runtime. When I run the program, I get the default values of the variables which has been assigned in the constructor `public account()`, and not those values which I am entering during the runtime. Could someone please explain the reason why this is happening.

Here is my code...

```
public class bank {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        account[] obj=new account[3]; 

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            obj[i]=new account();
            obj[i].entry();
            obj[i].display();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            obj[i]=new account();
            String res=obj[i].getCustomer_name();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, res);
        }

        account obj=new account();
        obj.entry();
        obj.display();
    }

}

class account {
    private String customer_name;
    private int acc_num;
    private double open_balance;

    public account() {
        customer_name="ADAM";
        acc_num=001;
        open_balance=100;
    }

    public void entry() {
        String customer_name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the customer name");
        String acc_num=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enterthe account number");
        String open_balance=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the balance");

        int acc_num1=Integer.parseInt(acc_num);
        double open_balance1=Double.parseDouble(open_balance);
    }

    public void display() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,customer_name);
    }

    public String getCustomer_name() {
        return customer_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when _you_ debug this problem?  At what point does the code not behave the way you expect it to?  What line of code deviates from the expected execution?  What are the states of the relevant objects when that happens?  You need to give us more information beyond "this doesn't work, fix it for me."

Answer (score 2):

The problem is shadowing: When you declare a variable inside a method with the same name as a member variable, it shadows the member variable.

E.g.

```
class MyClass{
    int var = 12;

    void shadows(){
        int var = 5;
        System.out.println(var); // prints 5
        System.out.println(this.var); // prints 12
    }

    void noshadows(){
        System.out.println(var); // prints 12
    }
}
```

Your fix:

```
public void entry()
{
    customer_name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the customer name");
    String acc_num_str=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enterthe account number");

    String open_balance_str=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the balance");

    acc_num=Integer.parseInt(acc_num_str);

    open_balance=Double.parseDouble(open_balance_str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Java expert, so this may just be a guess, but this code here looks incorrect:

```
public account()
{
    customer_name="ADAM";
    acc_num=001;
    open_balance=100;
}

public void entry()
{
    String customer_name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the customer name");
    String acc_num=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enterthe account number");

    String open_balance=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the balance");

    int acc_num1=Integer.parseInt(acc_num);

    double open_balance1=Double.parseDouble(open_balance);

}
```

In the `entry()` method you're re-declaring the `customer_name`, `acc_num`, and `open_balance` variables.  So when you reference them within that method you're referencing the newly-created local variables, not the class-level variables.

I'm surprised it even compiled, but I guess that just shows what I don't know about Java.  Were there no compiler warnings at all?

Comment: Java is okay with having local variables shadow member variables (and can also have member variables shadow superclass member variables). Most IDEs will warn you when you do that though.